# How to extract data from a column which has json type strings in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

Hi I have a dataframe

```
client_id| event_metadata                                      |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------
| 18890  |{Scripname:"DELL", Exchange: "NSE", Segment: "EQ" }  |
| 10531  |{Scripname:"NAUKRI", Exchange: "NSE", Segment: "EQ" }|
```

I want to extract event_metadata and store only ScripName along with client_id as a dataframe.

event_metadata is String and not json.

I have tried

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1.select('client_id', F.json_tuple('event_metadata', 'Scripname', 
 'Exchange','Segment').alias('Scripname',
  'Exchange','Segment')).show()
```

Its returning Null values

I have also tried using regex but showing error

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract

df1.withColumn("event_metadata", regexp_extract("event_metadata", "(? 
<=Scripname: )\w+(?=(,|}))", 0))\
 .show(truncate=False)
```

Desired Output:

```
client_id| Scripname|
+--------+-----------
| 18890  |  DELL    |
| 10531  |  NAUKRI  |
```

Comment: try `from_json()` requires a schema however. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

**`regexp_extract`**

```scala
df2.withColumn("Scripname",
      regexp_extract($"event_metadata", "^\\{\\s*Scripname\\s*:\\s*\"(\\w+)\"", 1)
    )
      .show(false)

    df2.withColumn("Scripname",
      expr("""regexp_extract(event_metadata, '^\\{\\s*Scripname\\s*:\\s*"(\\w+)"', 1)""")
    )
      .show(false)


    /**
      * +---------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+
      * |client_id|event_metadata                                       |Scripname|
      * +---------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+
      * |18890    |{Scripname:"DELL", Exchange: "NSE", Segment: "EQ" }  |DELL     |
      * |10531    |{Scripname:"NAUKRI", Exchange: "NSE", Segment: "EQ" }|NAUKRI   |
      * +---------+-----------------------------------------------------+---------+
      */
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your schema properly and read the data by `from_json`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType

schema = StructType([StructField('Scripname', StringType(), True), StructField('Exchange', StringType(), True), StructField('Segment', StringType(), True)])
df.withColumn('from_json', f.from_json('event_metadata', schema)) \
  .show(10, False)

+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|client_id|event_metadata                                             |from_json        |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|18890    |{"Scripname": "DELL", "Exchange": "NSE", "Segment": "EQ"}  |[DELL, NSE, EQ]  |
|10531    |{"Scripname": "NAUKRI", "Exchange": "NSE", "Segment": "EQ"}|[NAUKRI, NSE, EQ]|
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Now, your `from_json` column is struct type and can select the elements of them by `col('from_json.Scripname')`.

Comment: `event_metadata` is not actually a valid json, so using `from_json` doesn't help.